# Inserting pictures in tcolorbox

Tags: floats, wrapfigure, tcolorbox

I have a picture that I would put in a tcolorbox, but the image is too large and comes out.

The code:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\tcbset{enhanced,colback=cyan!5!white,colframe=cyan!75!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[every float=\centering, drop shadow, title=Esempio: misura della carica elettrica]
    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{center}
            \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{fig1}
        \end{center}
        \label{fig:fig1}
        \caption{Misura della carica elettrica}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    [Some text]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

The result:
[image]

I would like the box would fit the figure
What could I do? Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Why `wrapfigure` here? The code you provided has no text and I believe, that `wrapfigure` and `tcolorbox` do not behave well together

Comment: The wrapfigure is used to surrounding the image with the text

Comment: Yes, you have right, I have cutted it now for posting the code here. The text I need to insert is the same as showed in the screenshot.

Comment: I've deleted my answer since it's of no use to the wrongly used `wrapfig`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use two `minipage`s and load the `capt-of` package to write the caption through the command `\captionof`

```
\documentclass[demo]{report}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{capt-of}

\tcbset{enhanced,colback=cyan!5!white,colframe=cyan!75!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[every float=\centering, drop shadow, title=Esempio: misura della carica elettrica]
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
    \vspace*{0pt}
    \blindtext
    \end{minipage}\hfill%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\linewidth}
    \vspace*{0pt}
        \includegraphics[height=0.6\textheight,width=\linewidth]{fig1}
        \captionof{figure}{Misura della carica elettrica}\label{fig:fig1}
    \end{minipage}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @AndreaRosa you're welcome.

Comment: @PaulGessler The OP was misusing `wrapfigure` but it's clear from the posted image what he/she was trying to obtain.

Answer (score 24):

`tcolorbox` way of doing this is to add `sidebyside,sidebyside align=top,lower separated=false` as options to `tcolorbox` and you don't need `minipage`s.

```
\documentclass[demo]{report}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\tcbset{enhanced,colback=cyan!5!white,colframe=cyan!75!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[drop shadow, title=Esempio: misura della carica elettrica,sidebyside,sidebyside align=top,lower separated=false]
    \blindtext
    \tcblower
        \includegraphics[height=0.6\textheight,width=\linewidth,valign=t]{fig1}
        \captionof{figure}{Misura della carica elettrica}\label{fig:fig1}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can change the alignment by `sidebyside align=top` which takes `top`, `center` (default) and `bottom` values.